# Having trouble with IF ELSE statments

Tags: c#, if-statement, percentage

I am trying to do an assignment for class and I having some trouble with figuring out how to get the Marital status to go into the mathematical formula.  please keep in mind I need to keep the code simple and have to use if else statements since this is my 3rd week in class. Thanks in advance

here is the assignment so you can better see what I am trying to do.

> You will need to design an application that will prompt a user for his or her hourly pay rate, hours worked, and whether he or she is single, married, divorced, or widowed. It will then calculate the user's gross and net pay. If the user works more than 40 hours, overtime is calculated at 1 ½ times the regular rate and displayed separately. If the user is married, use a flat tax rate of 15%. If the user is single, use 22%, if divorced, use 23%, and if widowed, use 13% (I realize that these are not very realistic)

And here is my code so far:

```
double hourlyRate;
int hoursWorked;
string marriageStatus;
double Percent;

Console.WriteLine("Enter your Pay Rate");
Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Enter the hours you worked this week");
Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Enter your Marital status: M for married, S for single, D for divorced and W for widow");

if (marriageStatus == M)
    percent = .15
```

Comment: And what is your question sir? Don't you think you need to save what you get from the console in variables?

Comment: You are certainly getting compiler errors.  You should post them.

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting the marriageStatus variable based upon the user input.

So you'll need to:

```
marriageStatus = Console.ReadLine();

if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(marriageStatus)) {
marriageStatus = marriageStatus.ToUpper();
if (marriageStatus == "M") {
    //do married stuff
} else if (marriageStatus =="W") {
  //do widowed stuff
} else if (marriageStatus == "S") {
  // do Single Stuff
} else if (marriageStatus == "D") {
  // do divorced stuff
} else {
  // invalid input - error handling
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple problems:

1. You're reading from console - but not storing that input anywhere. You need to place what you read into a variable.
2. In your if statement you are comparing the variable `mariageStatus` to the variable `M` but `M` doesn't exist. What you're wanting to use here is to compare it to the literal `"M"` which is totally different.

Answer (score 0):

this will store the user input into a string

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

then you can go

```
if(input == "m" || input == "M")
{ percentage = 0.15;}
else if (input == "s" || input == "S")
{  percentage = .50; } 
else if (input = "w" || input == "W")
{percentage = .90; }
else
{
//there was an error
percentage = 0.0;
}
```